# Android Test Crashes

Tags: java, android

I've been practicing with Android Studio, and sometimes i get crashes which i have no explanation for. For example this one, its a button that silents your device whenever you press it.

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button silentButton;
    private AudioManager myAudioManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


     silentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.silentButton);

        silentButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Silent Mode Activated!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                }
        );

    }

}
```

Note: when i created the project i chose Ice Cream Sandwich (4.1) and the devices i ran my code on were both Marshmallow (6.0 & 6.0.1)

why do i get crashes and how can i prevent it. thanks.

Update: the silent mode works now but the Toast doesnt?

Comment: Add the logcat to your question

Comment: @Kardio : Check the permissions first. if you have proper permissions then execute the onClick code.

Comment: @Kardio you haven't posted any LogCat, how can you expect anyone to help you out?

Comment: @Sufian because i don't know how to do that. the Android Monitor has loads of messages and views, and i don't know which one to show you guys for my post to be more informative..

Comment: @Kardio you must ask because otherwise no one's gonna help. So, in the LogCat, you'll see package filter (select your app package there), and in the dropdown at the far right select "show only selected application". Now clear the LogCat and run the app again. Copy paste the log into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

I think you modify AndroidManifest.xml to add necessary permissions.for same program visite below link to get more information about do same.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_audiomanager.htm

Comment: the silent mode worked! thank you
but the toast did not show

Comment: try runOnUiThread to display toast or else put toast message before seting RingerMode

Answer (score 1):

Heres everything fixed the silent mode and toast. Thank you all.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button silentButton;
    private AudioManager myAudioManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        silentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.silentButton);

        silentButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Silent Mode Activated!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                    }
                }
        );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

myAudioManager is not initialized. Your app will definitely crash there.

```
myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Try to initialize myAudioManager

```
myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Comment: all good thanks for your reply. however the toast did not appear